# Point meta not working for for coordinates plot, example page 186 PGFplots manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

On page 186 of the PGFplots manual Revision 1.12 (2015/01/31) an example of the use of `point meta` is given:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar]
            %\addplot[mesh,point meta=y,thick] {x^2}; % WORKS!
            \addplot+[point meta=explicit] coordinates
            {%
                (0,0) [1.0e10]
                (1,2) [1.1e10]
                (2,3) [1.2e10]
                (3,4) [1.3e10]
            }; % DOES NOT WORK! WHY NOT?
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the coloring of the graph is just blue everywhere. What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Add the `mesh` option: `\addplot+[mesh,point meta=explicit] coordinates`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the `mesh` or `surf` option to the `\addplot+` command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar]
            %\addplot+[mesh,point meta=y,thick] {x^2}; % WORKS!
            \addplot+[mesh,point meta=explicit] coordinates
            {%
                (0,0) [1.0e10]
                (1,2) [1.1e10]
                (2,3) [1.2e10]
                (3,4) [1.3e10]
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]